# Duplicated title page in r-markdown beamer presentation

Tags: latex, r-markdown, beamer

Im trying to include a title page customized in latex in my r markdown beamer presentation, but im getting two title pages in the output: one generated by R markdown and another one generated by the latex code that I included in the `before-body` option of the YAML header.

Is there any way to prevent r markdown from generating a title page so that I only get my personalized title page in the output?

Here is a MWE:

```yaml
---
author: my-name
title: my-title
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
output: 
  beamer_presentation: 
    includes:
      before_body: title-page.tex
---

## First frame

- some content

## Second frame

- some content
```

Contents of title-page.tex:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]

\inserttitle

\insertauthor

\insertdate

\end{frame}
```

I already tried adding `\AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\relax}` to a file included `in_header` but I still got two title pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of manually creating your title page, you can simply modify the `frame title` template:

```
---
author: my-name
title: my-title
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes: |
  \setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    \inserttitle

    \insertauthor

    \insertdate
  }

---

## First frame

- some content

## Second frame

- some content
```

Comment: Your suggestion solved my problem! Just one more thing: with this solution, how can I get a `plain` title page? I will edit the MWE to include this detail.

Comment: @Pedro If you have a new question, please ask a new question

Comment: It was not a new question, it was my MWE that was too minimal, sorry for that. I managed to solve this by adding `\thispagestyle{plain}` to the template definition. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Pedro Rule of thumb: if you modify a question in a way that invalidates existing answers this indicates that this is a new question. Your problem might not be solved by the existing question+answer because it was too minimal, but asking another more specific one does not cost you anything